# PHP ImageMagick - readimage not working for certain pdfs

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

I`m currently trying to run the readimage() function on PDFs.

Here is the current code:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->readImage($file_to_read);
// etc...
```

Thing is, most PDFs work fine with this code. But for certain PDFs, PHP just hangs at the function call, throwing no exceptions nor causing a fatal error. Does anybody have an idea as to why or a workaround?

Thanks.

**edit**: I just ran `$ gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r144 -sOutputFile=p%03d.jpg 8Jun2015.pdf` on the non-working pdf and it converted the image to jpg correctly. But readimage() still doesn't work on the same file.

Comment: Its most likely a Ghostscript issue, are you using the latest version?

Comment: I have 9.02 installed, from early 2011

Comment: Try upgrading to the latest

Comment: Can you post an example pdf that has a problem @ArnoldLam ?

Comment: @Danack Yep I'll post it now as an edit. Thanks.

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you try running the code from the command line through the command `strace -ff php testCode.php > strace.txt 2>&1` and 'tail' strace.txt in another cli window. That should either show where it is getting stuck, or it might just show that it's still being processed but very slowly.

Comment: Forgot to say, it works fine for me with gs 8.70 and ImageMagick 6.9.0-7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I have to specify the file path. The following code works.

```
putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin");
$im = new Imagick();
$im->readImage($file_to_read);
```

If it still doesn't work, you can "clean" the PDF using gs. Something like this:

```
$sh= shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/gs \
    -o /repaired_pdf/' .  $new_file_name . '\
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
    ' . $file_to_read);
```